# How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Safari on iPhone automatically creates links for strings of digits that appear to the telephone numbers.  I am writing a web page containing an IP address, and Safari is turning that into a phone number link.  Is it possible to disable this behavior for a whole page or an element on a page?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649702/how-do-you-dissable-phone-number-detection-in-mobile-safari

Comment: <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"> worked for for iOs 16 Safari

Answer (score 803, accepted):

This seems to be the right thing to do, according to the [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Introduction.html):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

If you disable this but still want telephone links, you can still use the "tel" URI scheme.

Here is the [relevant page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1) at Apple's Developer Library.

Comment: This simply doesn't work.  Not for web apps on iOS 4.3.1 anyway.

Comment: 4.2.1 on iPhone works; http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: This isn't really an answer per se -- i'm just trying to lend my voice to say that this works in iOS 4.3.3, at least for me. cheers

Comment: Can you do this on per element basis instead of turning it off for the entire page?

Comment: Just wanted to note this also works for recent versions, such as 5.1.1 which I'm on now.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this for emails?

Comment: Works nicely in my Cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 based project! using tel indeed lets you still recognize a phone number. +1

Comment: Works on Safari Mobile on iPad and iPhone running on iOS 7.x

Comment: Note that this does not work if you insert the `<meta>` tag with JavaScript (at least on iOS 7.1). The tag has to be in the HTML when the browser downloads it.

Comment: @Titanium This `<meta>` trick works fine for the mail app on iOS 7.1.2. Just insert `<meta>` tag into the `<head>` tag in your HTML mail. Please note that we cannot apply this trick to text/plain based mails.

Comment: Can this be applied on a case by case basis? For example, 1 number string on a page I don't want to be interpreted as a phone number, but keep the behavior for 6 others on a page that I do want to be automatically interpreted as a phone number?

Comment: @jpostdesign Since it's a meta tag, it applies on a per-page basis. Unless all the pages on your site share a common header and footer, it should be trivial to add the meta tag to just one page.

Comment: Thanks. This works on ionic as well, put it in index page.

Comment: Works well, also works for React Native WebView components (which are basically Safari wrappers I suppose anyway)

Comment: This works perfectly fine under IOS 12 in 2019! 

Comment: This works for Safari—but what’s the fix for Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: This did not work for me on an iPhone 13 running iOS 15.6.1. Instead, I wrapped the numbers in a `<code>` tag and that stopped it.

Comment: Does not work on 2023

Answer (score 70):

I use a zero-width joiner `&zwj;`

Just put that somewhere in the phone number and it works for me. Tested in BrowserStack (and Litmus for emails).

Comment: This works for me. I just add it before the first number.

Comment: I created an HTML email signature and this was the only solution that helped to prevent iOS 10 mail from falsely detecting a (non-phone) number as a phone number.

Comment: Neat solution. Worked fine on iPhone 6S(+)/iOS 9.

Comment: This is the only workable solution if you're asking Mobile Safari to load an XML file that uses an <?xml-stylesheet> directive to generate the HTML page. Mobile Safari converts any long number in the original XML into a "tel:" link, even though the source isn't HTML (!).

Comment: AWESOME: zero-width joiner &zwj;
This is the best solution fo random numbers that are getting converted to phone numbers!
So for example, if you have 345 456 789 - which you want to NOT be a phone number...
&zwj;345&zwj;456&zwj;789

Comment: Best solution for one-off cases. For example: when Safari thinks a certain element is a phone number and it isn't, but you don't want to override _all other_ instances of phone numbers on the page.

Comment: The `format-detection` meta tag sadly didn't work. But this worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 51):

To disable the phone parsing appearance for specific elements, this CSS seems to do the trick:

```
.element { pointer-events: none; }
.element > a { text-decoration:none; color:inherit; }
```

The first rule disables the click, the second takes care of the styling.

Comment: Great solution where you want to restrict styling/formatting in very specific location.

Comment: This is the best solution, IMO, since it doesn't require making any modifications to the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. Applied for Brave Browser on iOS

Comment: doesn't work in iOs 14 and 13 at least not when it's not a link

Comment: this is the best solution if you want to keep tel functionality and disable it in a specific place. thanks for it!

Answer (score 36):

Add this, I think it is what you're looking for:

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

Answer (score 33):

I was having the same problem.  I found a property on the UIWebView that allows you to turn off the data detectors.

```
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Comment: At last, a solution that worked for me.  Of course this will only work with people writing their own objective-c application using UIWebView, and not using the Safari app.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

#### Solution for Webview!

For PhoneGap-iPhone / PhoneGap-iOS applications, you can disable telephone number detection by adding the following to your project’s application delegate:

```
// ...

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    // disable telephone detection, basically <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    theWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll ^ UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;

    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

// ...
```

source: [Disable Telephone Detection in PhoneGap-iOS](http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/09/disable-telephone-detection-in-phonegap-ios/).

Comment: Went in to implement the awoodland's code before I read badger110 comment.  So there I am, in AppDelegate.m when it occurs to me that I've seen this somewhere.  I start looking around, find the checkbox in xib file and I think I've just discovered something magical.  I come back to post this glorious discovery and find badger110's comment was there all along.  TL DR: Read the comments first, ya knuckle head.

Answer (score 9):

To disable phone number detection on part of a page, wrap the affected text in an anchor tag with href="#".  If you do this, mobile Safari and UIWebView should leave it alone.

```
<a href="#"> 1234567 </a>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing since the `meta` tag didn't work. However, it's probably better done with `<a href="javascript:;">` to prevent side effects from a URL change.

Comment: This works for me in HTML email. I only wanted to disable one phone number, not all. I just added the style="text-decoration:none;" to the tag with the color to match the rest of the text, and you could change the cursor style too.

Comment: This worked great for me for some hidden javascript numbers I needed that safari was interpreting as phone numbers, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the `<a>` label with `javascript: void(0)` as `href` value. 
Example as follow:
`<a href="javascript: void(0)">+44 456 77 89 87</a>`

Comment: This helped me when needed to still use the default iOS styling and actions but ignore specific elements.

Answer (score 6):

Think I've found a solution: put the number inside a `<label>` element. Haven't tried any other tags, but `<div>` left it active on the home screen, even with the `telephone=no` attribute.

It seems obvious from earlier comments that the meta tag did work, but for some reason has broken under the later versions of iOS, at least under some conditions. I am running 4.0.1.

Comment: Hi Bob. If you want to put in HTML code examples, you have to wrap the code in backticks, `<like this>`. (Stack Overflow uses a formatting language called Markdown.) I’ll edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: That didn't ultimately work - when I reloaded the App, the link hiliting was back. I have resorted to adding a`#` character to the front of the phone number: according to the Apple doc "Apple URL Scheme Reference":
"Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number."

Comment: You should remove your answer, since it doesn't work.  As you yourself acknowledge in the above comment.

Comment: @Bob Nice clean tip. We had issues with HTML in an email. Wrapping in a label worked nicely +1, thanks

Answer (score 6):

My experience is the same as some others mentioned. The meta tag...

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

...works when the website is running in Mobile Safari (i.e., with chrome) but stops working when run as a webapp (i.e., is saved to home screen and runs without chrome).

My less-than-ideal solution is to insert the values into input fields...

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="border:none;" value="3105551212">
```

It's less than ideal because, despite the border being set to none, iOS renders a multi-pixel gray bar above the field. But, it's better than seeing the number as a link.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested this myself and found that it works although it is certainly not an elegant solution. Inserting an empty span in the phone number will prevent the data detectors from turning it into a link.

```
(604) 555<span></span> -4321
```

Comment: This is also the fix I ended up using and it work very well and is quite simple.

Comment: This isnt a good Answer, because you generate willful bad HTML.

Comment: The simplest solution, thank you, Jay!

Answer (score 4):

I had an ABN (Australian Business Number) that iPad Safari insisted on turning into a phone number link.  None of the suggestions helped.  My solution was to put img tags between the numbers.

```
ABN 98<img class="PreventSafariFromTurningIntoLink" /> 009<img /> 675<img /> 709
```

The class exists only to document what the img tags are for.

Works on iPad 1 (4.3.1) and iPad 2 (4.3.3).

Comment: Unfortunately, in Internet Explorer I get those broken image icons. Adding `width="0" height="0"` helps, but still a single pixel is displayed.

Comment: You don't need images, just put any HTML inside the number: <p>Not a phone: 112<span>34</span>56</p>

Comment: @Geert, set `line-height` and `font-size` to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but on an iPad web app.

Unfortunately, neither...

```
 <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

nor ...

```
&#48; = 0
&#57; = 9
```

... worked.

But, here's three ugly hacks:

- replacing the number "0" with the letter "O"
- replacing the number "1" with the letter "l"
- insert a meaningless span: e.g., `555.5<span>5</span>5.5555`

Depending on the font you use, the first two are barely noticeable. The latter obviously involves superfluous code, but is invisible to the user.

Kludgy hacks for sure, and probably not viable if you're generating your code dynamically from data, or if you can't pollute your data this way.

But, sufficient in a pinch.

Comment: “Depending on the font you use, the first two are barely noticeable” Unless the user has set iOS to [read the content out to them](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/accessibility.html). Then it’d be pretty noticeable.

Comment: For accessibility (like text reader mentioned above), or if the user copy/pastes into the phone app, this just breaks things. Also, in general if a spider from Yelp or Google or the like is indexing a business, and pulls the wrong phone number, that's no good.

Answer (score 2):

`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` does not work for emails: if the HTML you are preparing is for an email, the metatag will be ignored.

If what you are targeting are emails, here's yet another ugly-but-works solution for ya'll:

Example of some HTML you want to avoid being linked or auto formatted:

```
will cease operations <span class='ios-avoid-format'>on June 1,
2012</span><span></span>.
```

And the CSS that will make the magic happen:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait){
span.ios-date{display:none;}
span.ios-date + span:after{content:"on June 1, 2012";}
}
```

The drawback: you may need a media query for each of the ipad/iphone portrait/landscape combos

Answer (score 2):

A trick I use that works on more than just Mobile Safari is to use HTML escape codes and a little mark-up in the phone number. This makes it more difficult for the browser to "identify" a phone number, i.e.

```
Phone: 1-8&#48;&#48;<span>-</span>62&#48;<span>-</span>38&#48;3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try encoding them as HTML entities:

```
&#48; = 0
&#57; = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Sencha Touch app solved with meta tag (`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`) in index.html of app.

Answer (score 1):

This answer trumps everything as of 6-13-2012:

```
<a href="#" style="color: #666666; 
                   text-decoration: none;
                   pointer-events: none;">
  Boca Raton, FL 33487
</a>
```

Change the color to whatever matches your text, text decoration removes the underline, pointer events stops it from being viewed like a link in a browser (pointer doesn't change to a hand)

This is perfect for HTML emails on ios and browser.

Comment: Looks to me like this sets the color explicitly. In other words, it will be gray no matter what.

Comment: “pointer events stops it from being viewed like a link in a browser” — in a browser that supports `pointer-events`, sure. If the user is viewing your HTML e-mails in [IE 10, however, no good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: The question is about suppressing detection of phone numbers, not mailing addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to remove the linking, it makes it very user friendly to have th eoption.

If you simply want to remove the auto editing, but keep the link working just add this into your CSS...

```
a[href^=tel] {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration:inherit;
}
```

Comment: well, I cannot say about the original poster, but in my case Safari is guessing phones that are not actually phone numbers, they are financial data

Comment: The question is about link detection on telephone numbers, not editing them.

Comment: In some cases you may have a phone number on a website where you need to perform some other operation than making a phone-call like pulling up an option to edit it, or the ability to click-and-drag it to somewhere else.

Comment: he does not want to have ip addresses linked as phone numbers

Comment: This worked for me when Safari was adding link styles to random numbers in the same div. Set everything to inherit for the tel element

Answer (score 1):

I too have this problem: Safari and other mobile browsers transform the VAT IDs into phone numbers. So I want a clean method to avoid it on a single element, not the whole page (or site).
I'm sharing a possible solution I found, it is suboptimal but still it is pretty viable: I put, inside the number I don't want to become a `tel:` link, the `&#8288;` HTML entity which is the [Word-Joiner invisible character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405917/2477547). I tried to stay more semantic (well, at least a sort of) by putting this char in some meaning spot, e.g. for the VAT ID I chose to put it between the different groups of digit according to [its format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_identification_number) so for an Italian VAT I wrote: `0613605&#8288;048&#8288;8` which renders in 0613605⁠048⁠8 and it is not transformed in a telephone number.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace the hyphens in your phone number by the  character `‑` (U+2011 'Unicode Non-Breaking Hyphen')

Answer (score 1):

I was really confused by this for a while but finally figured it out. We made updates to our site and had some numbers converting to a link and some weren't. Turns out that numbers won't be converted to a link if they're in a <fieldset>. Obviously not the right solution for most circumstances, but in some it will be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the meta tag to turn off format detection did not work for me. I was trying to display a zoom meeting ID in a `<p>` tag along with other text and iOS was turning that ID into a tel link. Additionally, I was targeting tel links via `a[href^="tel:"]` in order to give them custom styling so disabling the styles on tel links was not an option.

The solution I found was to wrap the ID number in a `<code>` tag. This seems to prevent iOS from messing with it.

Answer (score 1):

For WKWebView, the Swift equivalent to none is the following:

```
wkWebView.configuration.dataDetectorTypes  = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the number down into separate blocks of text

```
301 <div style="display:inline-block">441</div> 3909
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this is a workaround.