# only add href="tel:" when detects mobile device

Tags: html, css, smartphone

I list a phone number on my website at the moment and it is currently linked to 
"tel:myphonenumber"... how can I remove this a href unless the site is loaded on a mobile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an <a href> only active on mobile devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409089/how-can-i-make-an-a-href-only-active-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: seems to be the same sort of question.  how can I tell if the vcard is actually working?   I don't know how to clear cache on an iphone to test with and without the div's...

Comment: I would think some JavaScript could accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here
[How can I make an <a href> only active on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409089/how-can-i-make-an-a-href-only-active-on-mobile-devices)

You should use microdata. As Mobile phones will recognize it, and it won't affect normal web browsers.

```
<div class="vcard">
    <div class="tel">
        12345555555
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
 <td><a href="tel:888888">888888</a></td>
```

***CSS***

@media screen
and (min-width: 1224px) {
   a[href*="tel:"] {
       pointer-events: none;
   }
}

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately there is no way to accomplish that.

---

Comment: As you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409089/how-can-i-make-an-a-href-only-active-on-mobile-devices), there is a way...

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this.