# Prolem in iphone, ipad jQuery currency formatting

Tags: jquery, currency-formatting

I am facing some strange problem, I am using jQuery `formatCurrency` to format currency.

It's working in all browsers but not accurate on iPhone, iPad.

Here is my jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.itemprize').formatCurrency({colorize:false, region: 'it-IT' }); 

        console.log("Prize Formating");
        });
</script>
```

Here is my html markup:

```
<span class="itemprize"> 1590000</span>
```

On the iPhone the currency format like this

[image]
all browser the format looks like this
[image]

Here is the url where I can download the currency converter plugin

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage

Comment: What is the value you're expecting?

Comment: the format like this **1.590.000**

Answer (score 0):

I added this `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` to my page.tpl.php file and it worked! It was reading the number as a phone number which was affecting formatCurrency.

[Disable telephone number detection on iPad desktop web links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268413/disable-telephone-number-detection-on-ipad-desktop-web-links)