# iPhone making a plain number in to a linked phone number

Tags: iphone, ios, html, tel

I'm having an issue where I have a number displayed on my webpage that is NOT a phone number (it's a simple confirmation number without a link, just text on a page) is being converted in to a clickable link to call the number for ios users on mobile devices.  It's basically treating it as though I have made the number a link with a tel: protocol, even though it has no such markup. has anyone else seen this, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268413/disable-telephone-number-detection-on-ipad-desktop-web-links

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)