# Stop auto-detect phone numbers in Phonegap app for iOS (Bug)

Tags: html, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm developing an **iOS** app with **Phonegap Build** and JQM.

Is an app to generate math problems and some times I'm using big numbers that iOS interprets like a "phone numbers" and automatically converts into links. According the [PGB documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences) if add `<preference name="detect-data-types" value="false" />` into the `config.xml` this stop.

The preference added into the `config.xml` seems work good until I click a button, and the numbers are converted automatically into links, like if the preference was ignored.

The actions of the buttons are just for copy to clipboard and print, using this [clipboard plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/67) and this [printer plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/916). This should don't affect the numbers (at least that is what I think).

I've tested in iOS 6, 7 and 8, in all do the same.

Any idea how to stop this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Or set a property in the **UIWebView**

```
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

and have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649702/how-do-you-dissable-phone-number-detection-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: When I add the `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` seems to be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: How to auto detect the phone number -- above is the solution of avoiding auto detect ?