# How iPhone *not* format texts like "2007-2010" as phone numbers

Tags: html, iphone

HI friends,

Is there a way to make iPhone *not* format texts like "2007-2010" as phone numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Can you tell us what you want the result to be? You can always remove the characters you don't like manually: `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]`

Comment: @Jeff B and @Aurum :

Thanks for your response. I have got the solution.

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Answer (score 0):

the UIWebView has a property called:dataDetectorTypes you can set it to whatever data you want to detect, therefore make it linkable( or not in your case)