# iPhone safari treats numbers as a tel url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-safari, mobile-website, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Hello All,

I am developing a mobile web application. In a certain web page I need to display a number to the user. I am using MS ASP.Net 3.5 MVC 1.0. So, my view model has string to display the number on the view. But the iPhone converts the number on the screen as a tel url link.
It works fine on browsers.
Any one with any idea why its happening and how to get rid of it?