# HTML format looking fine on android but not on iphone

Tags: android, iphone, html, ios

I am sending mail with html format and it's format is below

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "<b> Your Last Alert: </b> <br/><br/>  On " + "<font color=\"red\"> " + mDate
                + "</font>" + " at " + "<font color=\"red\"> " + mTime + "</font>" + ", " + "\"<font color=\"red\">" + model + "</font>\""
                + " reported that its battery level was down to " + "<font color=\"red\"> " + batteryLevel + "%.</font>"
                + "<br/> You might want to get it on a charger before it's too late! <br/><br/><br/><br/><b> Do you know where \""
                + "<font color=\"red\">" + model + "</font>\"" + " is? </b><br/><br/> Click " + "<a href=\"" + s + "\"> here </a>"
                + " to view in Google Maps.<br/> To find \"<font color=\"red\">"+ model +"</font>\" with the Last Alert app on another iOS device, click <a href = \"" + linkForiPhone
                + "\"> here </a>. <br/>" + "Android users, Click <a href = \"" + linkForAndroid
                + "\"> here </a>. <br/><br/><br/><b><u> Last Known Location : </u></b><br/> " + address
                + "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><b><u>GPS Coordinates</b></u> <br/>" + cutLat + ", " + cutLong
                + "<br/><br/><b><u>Altitude</b></u><br/>" + alt + " " + "<br/><br/><b><u>Location Accuracy</b></u>" + "<br/>" + diameter
                + " Diameter"));
```

***when i open this mail on android it's looking great
but on iphone it's not looking in proper format
it is showing like below***

[image]

in Android it is looking fine like below

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but try `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` in the `<head>` of your html page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mobile Safari/ iPhone Mail.app HTML design issues: prevent autolinking and styling auto-links (dates, addresses, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265443/mobile-safari-iphone-mail-app-html-design-issues-prevent-autolinking-and-styli)

Answer (score 0):

You can link directly to the maps app for an address using

```
<a href=http://maps.google.com/maps?q=address>address</a>
```

and probably avoid the mail app's auto-formatting.