# Disable address formatting in iOS email

Tags: html, css, meta

I'm testing our company newsletter and for some reason our company address in the footer is getting auto-linked in Mail on iPhone.  (Which we don't want)  I presumed the meta tag below would prevent it, but it is still happening:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no"/>
```

Does Apple use a different tag?

Comment: Is it location address or email address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265443/mobile-safari-iphone-mail-app-html-design-issues-prevent-autolinking-and-styli

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265443/mobile-safari-iphone-mail-app-html-design-issues-prevent-autolinking-and-styli

Comment: Interesting.  Ok, thanks, I think this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to the address' container element and declare it in your head style snippet. For example:

```
.appleLinksBlack a {color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;}
```

And the footer address like :

```
<span class="appleLinksBlack">This address is being auto-linked in mac devices, but with the class the problem is solved :) </span>
```

Find more resources in [litmus blog](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

This site has all the best practices to test:

https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
```