# How to disable the blue links on iOS Devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, css, jquery-mobile

This can be seen in time formatted text such as (00:10 - 10:55) & time select menu (08:00 AM).

Already tried below solutions, but doesn't work.

1. [Mobile Safari/ iPhone Mail.app HTML design issues: prevent autolinking and styling auto-links (dates, addresses, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265443/mobile-safari-iphone-mail-app-html-design-issues-prevent-autolinking-and-styli)
2. https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

Note: This HTML pages are created using JQuery mobile and this blue color links can be seen only when it is loaded inside an app. I couldn't see that issue when it loads inside the iOS mobile safari browser.

Tested devices: iPhone 4s, iPhone 5

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#datetime" style="color:#000 !important,text-decoration:none;">00:01</a>
```

It also helps to break up the text by replacing some of the characters with ASCII HTML codes.

Comment: Thanks dcc, I have already tried this. But the issue is still exist.

Comment: Please post a demo of your full code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and I will take a look and try to find a better solution because this solution should work.  I use this technique almost daily and it works without error. I'm curious to see why it does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Its working only for the time format such as (00:10 - 10:55). But couldn't apply for the time select menu (08:00 AM).