# Blue underline in html table in iPhone email client

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I'm getting a blue linked underlined of this code in iPhone email client:

```
<td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #f3f3f3; font-weight: bold;">2:20</td>
```

How can I remove it?

Update:

I have the following header and the problem remains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

IOS autolink some texts which looks like date & time, address and telephone numbers. That's what happens here.

[Here is an answer element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706408/4837847)
[Here are more answer elements](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices)

It says that you ca add meta tag (unfortunately not working on mail client, but on Safari):

```
<meta content="date=no" name="format-detection" />
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
<meta content="address=no" name="format-detection" />
```

You can add in `head` tags (didn't test).

```
<style>
    a[href^=date]{ color:#F00; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
```

You can wrap your text in span with style in head and inline

```
<style>
    .appleLinksBlack a {color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;}
</style>
<span class=”appleLinksBlack”>2:20</span>
```

And if none of those working, you can add this HTML special character : `&#8203;`in your text, which is a zero width space, avoiding ios to autolink stuff

Comment: No, the only way I found until now is td a {color:#000 !important; text-decoration:none;} but it's still 'linkable'

Comment: Answer edited : add &#8203; before or after colon or both .It's an HTML special char for "zero width space" avoiding ios mail client to autolink stuff

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-decoration: none;`

```
<td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #f3f3f3; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">2:20</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about [format-detection](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW5), a feature of iOS Safari.

`<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you'll need to wrap the time in an anchor, then remove the colour and underline from there...

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: text; color: #222;">2:20</a>
```