# Prevent Phone Number recognition on JqueryMobile

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, jquery-mobile

I have this problem using Jquery Mobile. The issue was I have a date value of "12/6/1999" that is displayed on a label. Now JQuery Mobile converted it to a link because it is recognize as a phone number. I'm not very sure if it's jquery that does that or the iPhone.

So, my first approach was I'm looking for a way to prevent jquery mobile to recognize phone numbers. Is there a way to do it?

If it's iPhone that does it, is there a way that I can disable it?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

This will tell safari to not detect phone numbers.

More info on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two seperate ways.

**HTML disabling**

```
<p datadetectors="off">Header text with number 9123 3456</p> 
<p>Body text with number 9872 4567</p>
```

Or **globally** on your uiwebview

```
webview.dataDetectorTypes=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the input element type set to? make sure it's set to date.

Example:

```
<label for="date">Date Input:</label>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/
- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. But I don't think it will work. The type of element that I'm using for displaying the date value is a "<sapn>" or "<p>" tag. So, basically the purpose is just to display the date value coming from a web service.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari I think @gsilvestrin has the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

What I did was something like this. Made the date as a href with no link.

```
<a href="#" class="unlink">2012-08-23/a>
```

Then applied CSS to modify the link to looks like texts.

```
.unlink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    cursor: text;
}
```