# IBM Worklight - How to disable Native device features?

Tags: iphone, css, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created my application using IBM Worklight in Eclipse. I have added the iPhone environment and installed successfully my application on my device, but I have noticed that in some screens numbers appear with an underline and when tapped it shows a dialog box with call function.

I have tried using `text-decoration:none` so that underline does not appear, but it is still appearing. I have tried:

#### HTML

```
<span class="bluelink" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton">40562231</span>
```

#### CSS

```
.bluelink { 
    color:#1238a6; text-decoration:none;
}
```

[image]

---

Another issue I am facing is that when using `alert()`, it shows the title title as the HTML filename like *MyApp.html*. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I believe this is an iPhone feature, as in that the phone itself adds a link on phone numbers. If I'm right you could try something like `.bluelink a { text-decoration:none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `alert()` use the `WL.SimpleDialog` API. [Explained here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_simpledialog.html).

```
WL.SimpleDialog.show(
   "My Title", 
   "My Text", 
   [{
      text: "First Button", 
      handler: function() {
         WL.Logger.debug("First button tapped"); 
      }
   }]
)
```

As for the phone number, try the option here: 
http://razoredgelabs.com/2013/03/how-to-stop-apple-ios-devices-from-styling-phone-numbers/

There are also the following questions:

- [How do I remove the blue styling of telephone numbers on iPhone/iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers)
- [Mobile HTML rendering numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712475/mobile-html-rendering-numbers)
- [Prevent Phone Number recognition on JqueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239057/prevent-phone-number-recognition-on-jquerymobile)
- [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html