# Apparent HTML handling error in iPad/iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad

This is driving me balmy..

If you look at the following trivial web page including headers.... meant for embedded development in an Arduino (though the question has nothing to do with the latter).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
<link href='http://www.scargill.net/embed/embed.css' rel='stylesheet' /><title>strange page</title>
</head><body style='text-align:center'>
<br/>Time: 09:24:07 03/04/2012<br/>
<br/>Time: 09:24:07 03\/04\/2012<br/>
</script>
</body></html>
```

The two important lines showing time and date.... the first is a simple time and date display, the second is a desperate attempt to debug.. you can probably ignore it...

On ANY browser this displays fine... I've a copy at http://www.scargill.net/eh.htm

Any browser that is EXCEPT for Safari on the iPhone or iPad... something happens to that first line showing time and date, it gets part way through and simply stops.

This works on the iPad using OTHER browsers, but not Safari.

Can anyone help - why would a simple display of time and date mess up on the iPad and iPhone?

Comment: very strange, I note that the date is formatted as a link to a new contact, it seems there is some problem in the detection dataType. I note also that the contact that you can save is 070 3042012 or (tel: 07% 2003/04/2012 if you copy to the clipboard), the date is inverted.

Comment: also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Safari on iOS thinks that part of the date is a phone number and is trying to parse it.

You can stop Safari looking for phone numbers by adding the following to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

That should, hopefully, fix your issue.