# Phonegap app - prevent iphone from turning a number into a dialer link

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

I'm developing a mobile reporting application for a client using phonegap/jquery-mobile.  A certain report we have will output IDs that look similar to phone numbers.  The elements added to the dom look like:

```
<div>ID: 54321777</div>
```

While testing on the iphone, we noticed it would turn these IDs into links that open up the dialer app.  Is there some way to explicitly prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

[Source](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/keep-iphone-browser-from-turning-numbers-into-links)

Comment: Rather than re-posting a code-snippet without any explanation it's a good idea to close this question as an exact duplicate since the question is already answered on S.O.