# href iphone dialing incorrect phone number

Tags: html, mobile, href

I have created a link on my responsive website and I am trying to have the iphone dial the phone number when clicked. My phone is dialing the incorrect formatted number.

It is dialing **+353 (051) 877 222**

I wish to **051877222** if it is clicked inside Ireland

and I assume **+35351877222** if outside

I will have two types of callers, those inside the country and those outside the country, each requires a slightly different format. There is no one format that I know of.

```
<a href="tel://+353-51-877222">
    <h3 class="pull-right">+353 (0)51 877222</h3>
</a>
```

Dose anyone know of a way to achieve having the one formatted number? Thanks

Comment: Use the international dialling code for everyone?

Comment: the international version unfortunately will not work when clicked inside the country +35351877222

Comment: Really? I don't *doubt* you, but I am surprised, given that the +44 country code seems to work when dialled from within the UK. Unless I'm missing something obvious (long day...).

Comment: sorry you are right, long day for me too, so the problem I am having then is that the iphone is reading my code as +353 (051) 877 222 and not the number I have in the href

Comment: Have you tried the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/226131/82548 I don't know why the iPhone might even *try* to auto-link the text within an actual existing `tel` protocol link, but I figured it's worth asking.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, now I am aware that it is a Safari issue only. Unfortunately the suggestion the link did not work for me. I am going to update my question.