# Some paragraphs showing wrong color in safari on iOS devices?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

This particular part of website is showing blue color in all iOS devices, but it should show a pink #ca1f7b color.

```
<td valign="top" style="width: 20%"><p>04/2013 – heute</p></td>
```

CSS:

```
#content.cv  #right table td p{
    color: #ca1f7b !important;
}
```

This rule seems to work on Chrome and Firefox (can't test Safari for now), but on my iPhone and my iPad some of these table cells show blue color, and their html is identical to the working ones.

Chrome and Firefox show good results and the suggested rule is applied.

[image: Error example]

Answer (score 3):

It's probably the phone number detection done in iOS. iOS wraps such content in an `<a>` tag. 
Try adding the following meta tag in `<head>` to disable it

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

refer this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari) for more info.

Comment: @IvanIvković Your phone thinks that it is an phone number, IOS then makes it obvious to a user by changing the style of that bit of data.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to disable it then you can try this :

```
#content.cv  #right table td p a{
    color: #ca1f7b;
}
```

Comment: There were no a tag within the paragraphs.

Comment: If you are using no in your HTML in IOS it take it as phone number, and by default they linked up with that number that's the reason I told you to use anchor tag css you can check below links https://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices