# Disable iOS call prompt on selecting number

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

Is there a way to disable the native "Call" prompt?  Ex: this prompt occurs sometimes when you tap on a number (typically a phone number, on the web for example).

I have a calendar widget which is inadvertently triggering the call prompt so a quick fix would be to disable that type of prompt from occurring from within my app entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Can you add an image of the calendar widget and what is happening?

Comment: @BlackFrog no worries, there is an accepted answer.   Weird bug though - using https://github.com/mozbrick/brick-calendar the call prompt would only get triggered after tapping a date, but only if another native overlay (ie- list picker) was triggered before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hybrid apps you can use a meta tag to prevent iOS from adding a hyperlink around numbers.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.   If you're using PhoneGap Build for good measure I found you can also add <!-- <preference name="detect-data-types" value="false" /> --> to config.xml

Comment: Didn't knew about that one. Thanks for sharing.