# Nested anchor tags in iOS

Tags: html, ios, anchor

I'm building out a mobile menu and I have a link to a contact section as such:

```
<a class="global-navigation__chat">
    <span data-icon="chat"></span>
    <div class="nav-hidden-text">
        <span><?php print t('Chat With Sales'); ?></span>
        <span>+1 111 111 1111</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

The problem is that iOS seems to convert the phone number into an anchor tag and thus violates the nested anchor rule. When I view the page on my phone the anchor tag is placed after the preceding anchor tag:

```
<div class="nav-hidden-text">
<a class="global-navigation__chat">
    <span data-icon="chat"></span>      
        <span><?php print t('Chat With Sales'); ?></span>
</a>
</div>

<a href="tel:+1 111 111 1111">+1 111 111 1111</a>
```

Is this expected iOS behavior? Do I have to rewrite my HTML so that phone numbers do not have anchor wrappers?

Comment: _“Do I have to rewrite my HTML so that phone numbers do not have anchor wrappers?”_ – that would probably be the best, yes. This might not only happen on iOS, but on other systems as well; for example Skype IIRC has an option to rewrite telephone numbers to clickable links in desktop browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a web app / website running in mobile safari you can use

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227238/3821825) to disable the number detection.

If you are creating an iOS app with an UIWebView you can disable the automatic number detection either in the Attribute Inspector for the WebView in the Interface Builder / Storyboard or programmatically using

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.None
```

for no detection at all.