# OnsenUI ons-list-item is sometimes decorated in iOS

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui, monaca

Sometimes, but not always, the text in an onsen-list-item is decorated. It only happens with addresses in iOS. I have attached a screenshot below. Is there a way to prevent this?[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: I believe this is due to iOS auto-detecting it as a phone number.  When you click it, does it open the dialer?

Comment: Did my answer below help you out?

Comment: Yes thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:  [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Basically, you need:  `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Then you can explicitly set telephone numbers with the tel uri as defined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1