# RGB and CMYK are turning into hyperlinks in view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, erb

In my view layer I have a span class with some text inside with some RBG and CMYK values. These values are just strings to be displayed on the page. For some reason when the view is rendered this text is displayed as a hyperlink.

```
<span class="symbol">CMYK 94/29/9/0</span>
<span class="symbol">RGB 33 167 230</span>
```

[what view looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxH1.png)

Comment: please provide the whole html code, or a preview link.

Comment: Could it be malformed HTML? Have you tried validating with a HTML validator?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari