# innerHTML not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I just spent a few hours too many on a mysterious issue. I did not find *anything* via google. I want to share the finding.

Here's code that produces expected outcome on a PC, but unexpected on an iPhone:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = parseInt(input.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="input">1233453455</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Expected outcome:

```
1233453455
1233453455
```

iPhone outcome:

```
1233453455
NaN
```

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone changes the innerHTML content before executing javascript code! the "long number" is interpreted to be a phone number (which it isn't in this case) and adds a `tel` link inside the innerHTML. Observe what the `alert` windows reveals (execute below script on an iPhone):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
alert('input content: ' + input.innerHTML)
output.innerHTML = parseInt(input.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="input">1233453455</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

So there is the reason for the "unexpected result".

As for a solution: in my case, I simply switched to a different container for my text (I used a `data-`attribute):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = parseInt(input.getAttribute('data-test'));
```

```html
<div id="input" data-test="1233453455">1233453455</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Another seems to be described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari) (thanks to [@epascarello for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655110/innerhtml-not-working-on-iphone?noredirect=1#comment68541381_40655110)). But that will disable all phone number linking on your page...