# Number isnt showing on Iphone

Tags: html, iphone

```
<?php require('php/header.php') ?>
        <div class="contact main-content container flex-between">
            <div class="contact-info">
                <h1 class="align-center"><span class="title-span">Contact</span> Ons</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Telefoon: +31 6 12345678</li>
                    <li>Telefoon: +31 6 12345678</li>
                    <li>Email: info@example.nl</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form class="flex-column" method="post" action="php/sendmail.php">
                <input class="contact-input" type="text" placeholder="Naam: *" id="name" name="name" required>
                <input class="contact-input" type="email" placeholder="Email: *" id="email" name="email" required>
                <input class="contact-input" type="text" placeholder="Telefoon:" id="phone" name="phonenumb">
                <input class="contact-input" type="text" placeholder="Subject: *" id="subject" name="subject">
                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Bericht: *" id="message" name="text" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Verzend" required>

                <?php
                if (isset($_GET['message'])!= null )
                {
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo $_GET['message'];
                }
                ?>

            </form>
        </div>
        <iframe></iframe>
        <?php require('php/footer.php')?>
```

I'm developing a website, and everything works on android and windows and MAC.
 but as-soon as im' opening it on any I-phone the numbers are "gone" they are still there but they are auto marked as number so when you press it it will start a call but the number is gone its white. I cant fix it.
Can someone tell me how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this meta tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

[How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)