# How can i fix the issue of anchor attribute in safari

Tags: php, wordpress, html, css

I have an issue with an anchor tag.I am using 619-618-1660 in my website , and the problem is when i check my website on safari browser or an iPhone the text written in (href="tel:619-618-1660") is showing.You can check the image in below link.

[image]

Comment: Probably this is a bad html. There are missing close tags. Checkout. But I wonder how it is only on safari!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag to the top of your html

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Interesting. It might be better to apply CSS rules to the resulting links to make them look right instead of turning off the sometimes-useful functionality, though.

Comment: Agreed. @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

The Issue has been resolved , there is a file with the name of print.css with this code.

body{background:white !important;color:black !important;}#nav,#sidebar,.sidebar,#skip{display:none;}#content{width:100%;float:none;background:transparent;}a:not(.logo a){font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;color:#06c;}a:not(.logo a):after{content:" [" attr(href) "] ";}p{font-size:14px;}#printOnlyMessage{display:block !important;}

and in this code that produces an error is

a:not(.logo a):after{content:" [" attr(href) "] ";}

so I remove this code and the error is resolved.