# Sending HTML Mail with Java, Phone recognizes Numbers as Phone Numbers

Tags: java, email, formatting

My Java program is sending an HTML-Email to a list of people. I chose HTML so I can change the formatting. Sadly phones recognize long Numbers as Phone Numbers and colour them Blue and underline them(like a link). Is there a way to suppress this from the side of my program?

I'm really stuck here and it kind of destroys my formatting, can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Start with a Google search. I immediately found several answers including the duplicate above.

Comment: @Jason But is that universal or does it only work on Safari?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Jason I did some Google Research but nothing was exactly like my problem (Html Mail) and nothing fixed the issue so I opened this thread. Think its just my Phone (Huawai P9 Lite)